# How to know who overrides the rule in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I observe stroked out rule in Chrome:

[image]

How to know the reason of striking out?

Comment: Switch to "computed" panel and expand the properties.

Comment: @wOxxOm there are millions or properties there; unusable panel

Comment: @Dims there's a filter bar at the top of the **Computed** pane which allows you to focus in on specific properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the panel `Computed`. You can there hover the property `font-family` for example. On the end of the property name there is a arrow. You can click on this arrow to jump to the rule on panel `Styles`. The rule jumped to is the rule who overwrites all the other stroked out rules.

[image]

> **Note:** The overwritten properties are darker then the properties with default values. So in this example `font-family` and `font-size` are overwritten.

---

**You want to see only the overwritten properties?**
You can uncheck the `Show all` checkbox at the top right of the property list so only the overwritten properties are shown in the panel `Computed`.

[image]

Comment: Why isn't this possible from Styles panel directly?